# Hostname of pods in same statefulset can not be resolved

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, kubernetes-statefulset, coredns

I am configuring a statefulset deploying 2 Jira DataCenter nodes. The statefulset results in 2 pods. Everything seems fine until the 2 pods try to connect to eachother. They do this with their **short hostname** being *jira-0* and *jira-1*.

The jira-1 pod reports *UnknownHostException* when connecting to jira-0. The hostname can not be resolved.

I read about adding a **headless service** which I didn't have yet. After adding that I can resolve the FQDN but still no luck for the short name.

Then I read this page: [DNS for Services and Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) and added:

```
      dnsConfig:
        searches:
          - jira.default.svc.cluster.local
```

That solves my issue but I think it shouldn't be necessary to add this?

Some extra info:

- Cluster on AKS with CoreDNS
- Kubernetes v1.19.9
- Network plugin: Kubenet
- Network policy: none

My full yaml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: jira
  labels:
    app: jira
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: jira
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: jira
spec:
  serviceName: jira
  replicas: 0
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: jira
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jira
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: jira
        image: atlassian/jira-software:8.12.2-jdk11
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /jira/status
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 120
          periodSeconds: 10
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /jira/
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 600
          periodSeconds: 10
        envFrom:
          – configMapRef:
              name: jira-config
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
      dnsConfig:
        searches:
          - jira.default.svc.cluster.local
```

Answer (score 2):

> That solves my issue but I think it shouldn't be necessary to add this?

From the [StatefulSet documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/):

> StatefulSets currently require a Headless Service to be responsible for the network identity of the Pods. **You are responsible for creating this Service.**

> The example above will create three Pods named web-0,web-1,web-2. A StatefulSet can use a Headless Service to control the domain of its Pods.

The pod-identity is will be subdomain to the *governing service*, eg. in your case it will be e.g:

```
jira-0.jira.default.svc.cluster.local
jira-1.jira.default.svc.cluster.local
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I was referring to the dnsConfig not the headless service

Comment: Aha, should I create separate headless services for each pod in the statefulset? I only created 1 called jira as you can see at the top of the yaml

Comment: Hmm that's far from ideal. Every time the replicas is increased a new service would have to be created. On https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/ only 1 headless service is used. But they don't mention dns resolution for the short hostname. So I guess the solution I'm using with dnsConfig is not that bad after all.

Comment: You are right, I updated my answer. The pods will be subdomain to the main service. You should not need to manually add dns configs.

Comment: Also beware the DNS caching documented on https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#stable-network-id